# Dynamically Size Div

Tags: css, html, formatting

I'm doing some HTML and am running into an issue with my left and right column divs not scaling based on the content inside them as well as in proportion to the rest of the page.

Here's my example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0KaF.png

And my CSS for each of the divs:

```
#wrapper{
    background:white;
    width:1280px;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black; /* black border */
    margin:auto; /* centre this div */  
}
#header{
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#leftmenu{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding:.5em;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-left:2px solid black,
}
#rightmenu{
    width:180px;
    float:right;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding:.5em;
    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
#content{
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:120px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
#footer{
    clear:both; /* push footer under other divs */
    height: 70px;
    background-color:white;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 70%; 
}
```

How can I ensure that my divs resize based on the content in my other divs?

Thanks!

Comment: if your column divs have the 'other' divs as parent, they should resize accordingly I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, here's a stab at it:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hf8q/) here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hf8q/

CSS

```
html, body  {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 2px); /* for border */
}

#leftmenu, #rightmenu {
    height: calc(100% - 234px); /* for header, footer */
}

#wrapper {
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* black border */
    margin:auto;
    /* centre this div */
}
#header {
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#leftmenu {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding:.5em;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-left:2px solid black;
}
#rightmenu {
    width:180px;
    float:right;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding:.5em;
    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
#content {
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:120px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    /* push footer under other divs */
    height: 70px;
    background-color:white;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 70%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="leftmenu"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="rightmenu"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. My only question is am I able to "crop" the layout a little bit? Sorry if that doesn't make sense, basically now the design is responsive according to window size but it takes up the entire window. How can I alter it so that there's some whitespace on either side?

Comment: @fred02138 This code does not work. When we write something inside content, right menu moves downward.Check your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by wrapping `#leftmenu`, `#content` and `#rightmenu` in a div that is displayed as a table. And display the three children as a table-cell:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">#header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftmenu">#leftmenu</div>
    <div id="content">#content</div>
    <div id="rightmenu">#rightmenu</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">#footer</div>
```

CSS (without colors, padding, font sizes and stuff):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header{
    height:90px;
}
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
#leftmenu{
    width:100px;
}
#rightmenu{
    width:180px;
}
#content{

}
#footer{
    height: 70px;
}
```

And a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/V67Vs/).